# Passing an entire ViewModel into a DisplayTemplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

We are doing our damnedest to NOT use RenderPartial but instead to use EditorFor and DisplayFor in 100% of cases. However, there is one scenario that we haven't been able to get to work so far: When the partial view needs the entire ViewModel, or in other words, when it needs to be `Html.DisplayFor(m => m, "MyTemplateThatNeedsTheEntireViewModel")`. It works fine if it's `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prop, "MyTemplateThatOnlyNeedsTheOneProperty")` but we can't pass the entire ViewModel in.

Is there a way to achieve this that will work both with `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor`?

What I see now is that either nothing (or perhaps whitespace) is rendered to my markup. However, both the compiler and ReSharper seem to think my syntax is just fine. Changing my code to call RenderPartial works perfectly, but this is what I'm trying to avoid.

I try these three lines. The RenderPartial works perfectly, the EditorFors do not work (eventual markup is an empty string or whitespace):

```
<% Html.EditorFor(m => m, "RetailPriceRequests/PriceRequest/PriceRequestLoadGrid"); %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m, "RetailPriceRequests/PriceRequest/PriceRequestLoadGrid") %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RetailPriceRequests/PriceRequest/PriceRequestLoadGrid.ascx", Model); %>
```

Comment: what is the type of each of the DisplayTemplates?

Comment: They're very custom ViewModels. For example, we have a `BusinessDetailsViewModel` where we pass it to a `BusinessSummary` (always-on-screen info) and `BusinessDetails` (contents of one of many tabs) and then various properties off of the `BusienssDetailsViewModel` get passed into display/editor templates in additional tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If your DisplayTemplate is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ExampleModel>" %>

DisplayFor(m => m, "ExampleModel")
```

should work

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ExamplePropertyModel>" %>

DisplayFor(m => m.ExampleProperty, "ExamplePropertyModel")
```

should work

One issue you could be that something is null, in which case it probably shouldn't be hitting the View at all, but you can get around this by writing:

```
RenderPartial("ExampleModel", Model ?? new ExampleModel());
```

or

```
RenderPartial("ExampleModel", 
    (Model ?? new ExampleModel() { ExampleProperty = new ExampleProperty() })
        .ExampleProperty ?? new ExampleProperty());
```

Comment: Your very first example is exactly what I am trying to do and no HTML inside of the ExampleModel template renders (even for just a Hello World type of template). Your last two examples do not work - you cannot perform logic inside of that lambda expression, only specify a property. `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Comment: are you calling one DisplayTemplate from another?

Comment: BTW, I do `DisplayFor(m => Model ?? new ExampleModel(), "ExampleModel")` all of the time without issue... that exception you're seeing might be the problem

Comment: First question, yes, we have a sophisticated nesting of templates calling each other. However, I've reproduced this in a hello world scenario too. Are you SURE you've done that all the time? That exception is what I expect, not something that surprises me.

Comment: I have had problems with trying to load another DisplayTemplate from within a DisplayTemplate, in which case I just used RenderPartial to get around that. Maybe it's a feature/bug?

You're right, I use that type of coding doing a RenderPartial, not DisplayFor... whoops!

Comment: Rather, I had to use `Html.Partial` like this: `<%=Html.Partial("DisplayTemplates/MyDisplayTemplate", Model)%>` to achieve the nesting

Comment: No, this isn't a template inside a template issue. It is very specific to `DisplayFor(m => m, "foo")`. We have a bajillion templates inside of other templates. (we probably have ~150 templates right now)